# Compile without extraneous information

Tags: c, gcc

Suppose I have a simple C file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("It works!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**How can I compile C source code so that the resulting binary does not leak information about me?** ie. compile an anonymous binary

If I simply use

> gcc main.c

on the above source

and then

> strings a.out

I get output such as

> GLIBC_2.2.5

Going through a.out in a text editor, I can find

> lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
>
> GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Even after `strip`ing a.out, there is still a lot of identifying information in the binary

**EDIT:** *Reason for asking this question*

I am young and hoping to get a job in programming.

However, I would like to create a "test" repo before creating a "professional" one.

I know I can delete the "test", but it may be archived somewhere (archive.org).

I cannot make a "private" repository as it is a paid feature

The "test" repo will contain code I have already written (but the style of code is not at par to how I now code), I would also like to compile and add it to a GitHub release.

The "pro" repo will contain code I write from now on.

I do not want employers to know the authors are the same person

Comment: *Why* do you want this? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: Where is the personal information?

Comment: @EdHeal maybe the compiler is the OP here?

Comment: I'd like to compile and distribute binaries across several public repositories, but don't want many people to know I am the same person (obviously posting using a different account)

Comment: How can  the above info identify you?

Comment: Umm.. won't they notice that the binary executable is the same size and has the same checksum?

Comment: It's not _personal_ information, but I'd like to replace anything that is not generic to generic (eg. browsers can be identified by user-agent and Tor Browser uses a generic user-agent)

Comment: That sounds like you're doing something nefarious.

Comment: @MartinJames I am not distributing the same binary (using different source) - If you compile the above source, I can almost guarantee the checksum will be different from mine (MD5: 371643872c764d70bc355b6e29c114dd)

Comment: Even Tor Browser has "good" users and "bad" users, some are for genuine research / journalism, but some content is illegal to post publicly (in some countries)

Comment: I don't like the intention and I think it would be unethical to help the OP in achieving their goal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please don't judge

Comment: @user2979872 Why shouldn't I?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Stackoverflow is for helping others not judging others. OP is not sitting in a court infront of you

Comment: @user2979872 SO is a community run website where each member is entitled certain tools and their own opinion on how to use them. We don't help here to virus-writers, suicide bombers and kitten killers.

Comment: There is a rule of law about conspiracy. I try to avoid getting wrapped up in that myself as I am identifiable.

Comment: @AvdnhracNTAd9ex:  You write at the end that there is still a lot of identifying information in the binary.  Can you provide more examples other than what you've posted?  Does the other identifying information consist of just library names and versions, or is there other stuff?

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are too cynical and extreme in your opinions. Please keep this to your self.

Comment: @user2979872 Are you judging me now? For my opinions? Hm...

Comment: @EugeneSh. You said it and you have it. While OP didn't say anything and you were jumping to conclusions guessing this could be for virus, kitten killers etc.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. we should not worry too much about potential viruses & exploits. If OP is asking such a very "advanced" questions, he is not very dangerous :)

Comment: @user2979872 You know - it is not very common to remove all the information from binary. Doing it in the real life you would definitely drive some attention of the law enforcement agencies. Anyway - I think no answers or advices shall be given.

Comment: @indiv As far as I know, it is only the dynamic linking that is identifiable (given enough samples)

Comment: @PeterJ I know that is not very common (or why couldn't I easily find it online?)... Maybe it is because few people know how to strip identifiable information in the first place

Comment: I would have thought having those strings in the binary would make it less identifiable (as they are very common). Having a binary without them would indicate that the person has something to hide

Comment: @AvdnhracNTAd9ex or maybe those who know do not want to feed ignorant home made hackers/pirates/terrorists/crackers

Comment: @PeterJ How do you distinguish between ignorant and those wanting to learn? Besides, it is a lack of knowledge that makes us want to learn

Comment: @EdHeal any additional information will make it more identifiable (take for example the **full** results at https://panopticlick.eff.org/)

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, it would indicate the person has something to hide (their identity), but perhaps it is for the greater good

Comment: You are creating a binary. Not visiting a web site

Comment: @AvdnhracNTAd9ex In all clans, societies, sects - there is some knowledge not available for everyone. Identity hiding, virus methods writing is this kind of knowledge. You do not need to learn it. If you want to learn it is suspicious, as it does not have any legal practical use.

Comment: @PeterJ You do realize that polymorphic code is easily obtainable, right? Also, I would say Tor Browser is identity hiding knowledge (just look at the source code and/or read blogs to see how it works)

Comment: You are getting more and more suspicious

Comment: @PeterJ Is learning to serve pufferfish suspicious? It has potential to be an excellent dish, yet also the potential to poison and kill humans

Comment: What positive potential can be in "*compile and distribute binaries across several public repositories, but don't want many people to know I am the same person (obviously posting using a different account)*"? Please explain.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why would the creators of Bitcoin want to publish the implementation under the name "Satoshi Nakamoto"?

Comment: @AvdnhracNTAd9ex They have had their reasons. I asked about yours.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How do you know the backstory of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/how-to-recover-a-lost-zip-file-password is true? How do you (and other community members) know it isn't for their own nefariuos purposes?

Comment: @AvdnhracNTAd9ex You don't have *any* backstory. If you can come up with a somewhat convincing one it might suffice even if not very true.

Comment: @EugeneSh. See update to post

Comment: There's no good reason to answer this question. It's not like you're writing malware for the sake of learning about it, or learning pentesting, or hacking for the sake of fixing bugs. If you were out for knowledge then you would figure it out on your own.

Comment: @Darren I know I can just fire up a VM to compile, but it seems like overkill for such a simple thing

Comment: If anyone doesn't like this question I would recommend they close it and go onto another question

Answer (score 0):

`GLIBC_2.2.5` and `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` needed for dynamic linking.  You can only get rid of that by using static linking (which is not recommended and barely supported on GNU/Linux).

To remove the compiler identification, compile with the `-Qn` option.

Comment: -Qn is the default, and does not remove the .comment section that contains "Ubuntu". Try `strip -R .comment thebinary`.

Comment: I think the documentation is wrong, see the handling of `flag_no_ident` in `toplev.c`.

Comment: On a trivial example, I am getting the same binary whether I use -Qn, -Qy or nothing...

Comment: Interesting. What's your target? I see the `.ident` suppression with `-Qn` on Debian and Fedora.

Comment: Debian testing, compiling `int main(){}` with the system gcc: `gcc m.c -Qn` (or -Qy or nothing) and checking the md5sum of a.out.

Comment: I just tried `gcc-7 -Qn -O2 -S -o- -x c - < /dev/null | grep ident` with current Debian sid (amd64), and it does not show any output for me.

Comment: @MarcGlisse also getting the same binary here